# Python Logger does not write to file, still generates logs

Tags: python, django, file, logging, pm2

have been struggling with this.

I had created a logger for a class instance that gets created every 30 seconds or so. To prevent duplicate logging, I added a `hasHandlers` check, but now the results do not get logged to the file. I can see the logs being generated in PM2 though, so some portion of the logging *is* working.

```
class ExampleClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.example_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('logs/example.log', when='D', interval=1, backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=False, utc=False)

        if not self.example_logger.hasHandlers():
            self.example_logger.addHandler(handler)
            
        self.example_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

For the use-case, a new instance of this class needs to be created every 30 seconds. It is created via a django command. I would like to avoid any logging duplication as that has been an issue in the past. The path to the log file exists, and if the file is not present, it is created. Yet not written to.

UPDATE: Still have not been able to figure this out.
Using `len(self.example_logger.handlers) == 0` as a check instead of `hasHandlers()` *seems* to do the trick but I still am looking for an explanation as to why `hasHandlers()` isn't working. I may try to create a custom logger, as I'm not very comfortable putting this into production without finding the root cause of the issue.

Comment: How are you logging? I think it simply logs to the wrong logger.

Comment: ```self.example_logger.error("This is an error")``` is how I'm currently doing it within the class.